# Unable to use setState in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, components, setstate

I have the following code that is not letting me set the state ever after getting mounted.

Here is the code

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Messages from '../locale/en/Messages';
import '../styles/base.css';

class AlertService extends Component {
    state = {
        message: '',
        classType: 'alert-info',
        isMessageSet: false
    }

    Messages = new Messages();

    componentDidMount = () => {
        console.log('This has mounted'); // This is working
    }
    componentWillUnmount = () => {
        console.log('Is this getting unounted ?'); // This is working, the component is not getting unmounted
    }
    setAlert = (key, type, isMessage, readMore) => {
        let message = isMessage ? key : this.Messages[key];
        let classType = 'alert-info';
        if (type === 0) {
            classType = 'alert-danger';
        } else if (type === 1) {
            classType = 'alert-success';
        }
        this.openMessage(message,classType);


    }
    openMessage = (message,classType) =>{
        this.setState({
            message: message,
            classType: classType,
            isMessageSet: true
        });
    }
    closeMessage = () => {
        this.setState({
            message: '',
            classType: 'info',
            isMessageSet: false
        });
    }
    render() {
        let classes = this.state.classType + ' ' + 'alertBox';
        return (this.state.isMessageSet ? 

                                        <div className={classes}>
                                           <div className="col-md-11"> {this.state.message} </div>
                                           <div className="col-md-1 closeAlert" onClick={this.closeMessage}> x </div>


                                        </div>

                                : null
        )
    }
}
export default AlertService;
```

I am geting the following error when trying to call the function setAlert from outside this component.
However if I set the `isMessageSet` property to `true` then on clicking the X and calling the closeAlert method, it works fine.

componentDidMount indicates that the component is getting mounted and componentWillUnmount is never getting executed , I am not sure what is wrong here

Error Message
 Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the AlertService component.

Comment: What do you mean by "outside of this component"?

Comment: I am calling the setAlert function of this component from another component when there a message to be displayed, by instantiating AlertService class.

Comment: Oh, there is a use case like this. Ok then, do not bother with my question.

Comment: Where are you calling it outside of component ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned in one of the comments that you are trying to call the setAlert function after instantiating the AlertService class, I suggest you to please take a look as to how you are doing that. The right way is:

this.AlertService = React.render(React.createElement(AlertService), mountnode) //mounts the component
this.AlertService.setAlert()  // now you can call the function

Depending upon your usecase you can do like above.

The thing with react is that the child component's methods cannot be called by the parent component. Since those are meant to be private to the child and should therefore be handled by itself. As a hack though we can make use of refs to call the child component's methods but that is not a recommended usecase for refs. Thid can result in bugs in you application.

The best way to achieve the prupose as @vijayst suggested is to change state of your parent component on an alert(whenever message is received) and pass it as a prop to the child. Now update the state for the child under componentWillReceiveProps().

Comment: thanks a lot componentWillReceiveProps did the job for me

Answer (score 1):

`setState` should not be called from outside the component. If you want to change the state from outside, use props.

And as the error message says, the component is not mounted. You could mount it by adding `<AlertService />` to the Layout.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you said you tried calling `setAlert` from another component, it doesn't work but when you called `closeMessage` it works as expected, but then I noticed you called `closeMessage` in this same component which would work as expected, if you want to call a function that belongs to this component in another component then you need to import the component into this component then pass the function to it so you would be able to call the function in the component. For example:

```
import AnotherComponent from '../AnotherComponenet'

<AnotherComponent setAlert={this.setAlert} />
```